# webdriverIO facing issue in unable to load spec files?

Tags: webdriver-io

Error:  Unable to load spec files quite likely because they rely on `browser` object that is not fully initialised.
`browser` object has only `capabilities` and some flags like `isMobile`.

I tried lot of ways but it's getting failed .

Answer (score 0):

I also have encountered this issue because I used to import all my classes with ES6 syntax (import smth from 'smth'). After adding babel.js this issue disappeared.

Try to install Babel, then set babel.config.js file:

```
module.exports = {
presets: [
    ['@babel/preset-env', {
        targets: {
            node: '16'
        }
    }]
]}
```

And you need add additional require property into wdio.conf.js to mochaOpts (or appropriate opts according to your framework):

```
mochaOpts: {
ui: "bdd",
foo: bar,
require: ["@babel/register"]},
```